# why code on global.asax run good when develop but not work on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

i have some code about rewrite url on global.asax.
It work very good when i build my web.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            string sDefaultPath = Context.Request.Path;

            switch (sDefaultPath.ToLower())
            {
                case "/trang-chu":
                    httpContext.RewritePath("/Default.aspx");
                    break;
                case "/gioi-thieu":
                    httpContext.RewritePath("/Contact/AboutUs.aspx");
                    break;

            }
        }
```

But when i deploy it on IIS6, window server 2003, it didn't work.

When i click to the link like: "http://scom:1122/gioi-thieu"
It show the error: "**HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found**"

Please help me fix it! thanks!